# Closing row gaps in excel

Tags: excel

I have the following in an excel spreadsheet:

```
  A          B         C
1 ID        Label     Text 
2 123        R        Some text  
3
4 456        S        Some more text
5
6 789        R        Even more text
```

But I want to close the row gaps so my excel spreadsheet can look like the following

```
  A          B         C
1 ID        Label     Text 
2 123        R        Some text  
3 456        S        Some more text
4 789        R        Even more text
5
6
```

I found the following https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/511-merge-rows-keep-data.html but it is not quite what I am looking for

**Question**: Is there an automated/easier way to close the row gaps, aside from doing this manually?

(I can do this manually by cutting and pasting but my excel sheet contains thousands of rows that contain these sort of row gaps)

Comment: maybe sort it ...?

Comment: Sort the range by any column and the blank rows will group together, at which point they can be multi-selected and then deleted if necessary

Answer (score 0):

You could do an index match.  In another column (say column D), simply do something like if(a3="", "", row()).  Then in another column rank each row if there is a value.  Something like if(d3="", "", rank(d3, $d$1:$d$6).  Create another column (say column E) that just goes from 1 to the end of the data set (increment each row by 1).  Finally do an index match like so:  index(A:A, match(d3, $E:$E, 0).

Answer (score 0):

Per `Jeeped` and `tehhowch`, the easiest way to accomplish the goal is to simply sort by column `ID` value